# Drop down attribute: "Please use letters only"

Tags: dropdown-attribute

I created a new product attribute ("Presentation") as a drop down menu, the two available values are "Aerosol" and "Pail". When I try to select one of these two attributes, I get the error message "Please use letters only (a-z or A-Z) in this field.

"Aerosol" and "Pail" comply with these rules, I also tried lower case, and there's no accidental space anywhere.

To me, this looks like a bug, but I might as well just be missing something. Would somebody know how to fix that?

Here's [how I set up the attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umzlI.png).

And here's [the error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLMXe.png).

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the attribute you created and check `Input Validation for Store Owner`, I guess you will not be able to change its value, either delete it and create again and this time select `none` for validation Or update directly in database for this attribute.

Comment: Very simple and very helpful. Thank you!